# Angular component interaction issue

Tags: angular, angular7

Angular component interaction issue. Data not getting to pass from Html to ts components. I'm using Angular 7.

**app.component.html**

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
</div>
<app-test [parentData]="name"></app-test>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'component-interaction';
  public name = "Vishwas";
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TestComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**test.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  template: `<h2>{{"Hello "+ parentData}}</h2>`,
  styleUrls: []
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() public parentData;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

[image]

Comment: How you are accessing that value? In child component?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale - Have a look at `test.component.ts`

Comment: `*ngIf` will do trick, Might be you are displaying a before it is available in Child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the public keyword in both parent and child component.ts, it should work fine

```
  public name = "Vishwas"; // public not necessary 

  @Input() public parentData;  //public not necessary
```

you are not accessing the parentData anywhere in the test component. Also add a ngIf to check the data accessible only if its available in the parent,

```
<app-test *ngIf="name" [parentData]="name"></app-test>
```

Just add a console.log inside ngOnInit() and see if its working

```
 ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.parentData);
 }
```

Comment: Nope, it's not working after your suggested changes

Comment: btw you are not accessing it anywhere

Comment: Thanks, its working. Any reason its not working with the `public` data type? Actually I am accessing value in `test.component.ts

`

Comment: I am not sure why by adding public keyword at both place start working again ?

Comment: it should work with the public data type as well, but its not necessary

Answer (score 0):

Check Your answer at this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6tmcn5.
I think there is format issue near:

```
`template: <h2>{{"Hello "+ parentData}}</h2>`,
```

i simply redited the Code to this.

```
template: `<h1>Hello {{parentData}}!</h1>`
```

check below image.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

first you remove public :

```
@Input() parentData: string; and set name = "Vishwas";
```

and

```
<app-test [parentData]="name"></app-test>
```